# What should I get the height() of to make list fill the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

IT WAS THE DEFAULT MARGIN ON THE `<UL>`!! SORRY
I've got a list of anywhere between 5 and 20 items and I want to make the whole list fill the height of the screen. So I'm finding the height of `<html>` and dividing it by the number of `<li>`s and setting this number as the height of each `<li>`. The problem is there is this roughly 20px white space at the bottom that comes up after the list. I think I need to find the height of the window or body or something instead. Here is some of my code:

```
var numRootOptions = $('.wrapper > ul > li').size();
var htmlHeight = $('html').height();
var newliHeight = htmlHeight / numRootOptions;
$('.wrapper > ul > li').css('height', newliHeight);
setInterval(function() {
    var htmlHeight = $('html').height();
    var numRootOptions = $('.wrapper > ul > li').size();
    var newLiHeight = htmlHeight / numRootOptions;
    var liHeight = $('.wrapper > ul > li').height();
    if (liHeight != newliHeight) {
        console.log('Different');
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: IT WAS THE DEFAULT MARGIN ON THE `<UL>`!! SORRY

Answer (score 3):

try [**innerHeight()**](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) instead of just .`height()`

Comment: Didn't work, is there always a ~20px difference between the height of html and the body?

Comment: It was margin on the ul, i should've checked that, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you should use `$(window).height()` or `$('html').innerHeight` as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Default margin on the `<ul>` was the problem. Sorry for the stupid question! Thanks y'all.